# Is "lay easy on someone" a real phrase?

Tags: expressions

I used "lay easy on someone" today, to mean "go easy on someone" (when we learned the person is going through a hard time). I strongly feel people use this phrase (English is my second language), but I can't find anything about it on Google. Is it a real phrase?

Comment: Not in American English (I can't speak for British usage).  But in American English we do have a phrase, "lay *off* *of* someone" to mean going easy on the person.  If spoken at the moment when the harsh treatment is happening, it's often shortened to just, "Lay off!"

Comment: We could also say something (a potentially disturbing act or idea, for example) ***sits** easy on [someone who has no qualms about it].* But I think the preposition ***on*** there is extremely dated, if not archaic - today, we'd usually use ***with**.*

Answer (score 1):

> I used **lay easy** on someone" today, to mean "go easy on someone" (when
>   we learned the person is going through a hard time).

*Lay easy* is slang and does not covey the sense you desire.

Better:

> - Go easy on X. (when we learned the person is going through a hard    time).
> - Lay off X.

- > Ease up on X.

[Green’s Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/search/basic?q=lay%20easy) provides the following:

> **lay-easy**
>
> sexually available or compliant